# How to specify a TTC font index in a Glyphs.FontURI property?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5, glyph, glyphrun

I want to put a TTC (True Type Collection) font file in FontURI property of a Glyphs.
I use .Net5.0

I found in the old silverlight documentation this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ms599247(v=vs.95)

> FontUri also supports TTC (TrueType Collection) fonts. You can index a specific font face offset in the  collection using the format collectionname.ttc#n where n is the index within the collection. You can  omit "#0" if you intend to reference the first font face in the collection.

But in  the net5.0 documentation this paragraph is not in the documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.glyphs.fonturi?view=net-5.0

I tried the #1 in the FontURI (for Cambria Math) but without luck.
[image]

Here is the code i tried to create the glyph font URI :

```
glyph.FontUri = new Uri(@"c:\Windows\Fonts\cambria.ttc#1");
```

Is there a way to render glyphs from a TTC file in .net5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a proper URI, in this case file://C:/Windows/Fonts/cambria.ttc#1.